# Why is there time delay using asyncio in django

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a system that judges code(python files) in given time with asyncio. This is how it works: In `judge.py`, it calls `processor.py` and write the output to a text file. `processor.py` basically excutes the given python file and track the time the code used.

`judge.py`

```py
import asyncio, time

async def cmd():
    try:
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
            "processor.py > output.txt",
            shell=True,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL)
        await proc.communicate()

    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        proc.terminate()
        print("X")

PROCESS_TIME_BOUND = 5

acceptable_time = 0.1

async def run():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(cmd(), PROCESS_TIME_BOUND + acceptable_time)
        print("A")

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("B")


loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

As you can see. There's a line `await asyncio.wait_for(cmd(), PROCESS_TIME_BOUND + acceptable_time)` because the async function takes time to excute way longer than the time that the python file actually takes. In my computer, while the python file ends in 0.000001 seconds, the async function takes around 3.4 seconds.

`processor.py`:

```py
import os, time, sys

start = time.time()

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    exec(f.read())

end = time.time()

print("PROCESS ENDED WITHTIN %.20f SECONDS" % (end-start))
```

Why and how does this time delay occur? Are there any ways to fix the time delay? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the python interpreter takes 3+ seconds to start on your system due to some misconfiguration? It wouldn't be unheard of.

Comment: @user4815162342 In that case, if I call `python [filename].py` directly in the command shell it will also takes 3+ seconds to start? I don't think it actually takes that long. But I noticed that `os.system()` takes long time too. I want to fix this because the system will give multiple inputs and runs the file multiple times. If I set a minimum time for the python interpreter to start it might delays the total time to judge a lot.

Comment: If the exact same thing happens with `os.system`, it's either due to python startup, or the shell. Try using `create_subprocess_exec` and give it the full path to the python executable (using `r"..."` to handle backslashes).

Comment: @user4815162342 how do I make output file without modifying the python executable?

Comment: Replace `stdout=DEVNULL` with `stdout=f` where `f` is the file object created with `open("output.txt", "wb")` or equivalent.